# How to prepend text from one txt file to multiple txt files

Tags: windows, batch-file, prepend

I have one intro.txt file with some text that I want to prepend to all .txt files

Example intro.txt

```
0
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:10,000
Subtitle BY Name
Synced By Name
```

I want to append it to the first line

File1.txt

```
    0
    00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:10,000
    Subtitle BY Name
    Synced By Name
    
    1
    00:00:11,000 --> 00:00:20,000 
    Hello
    2
    00:00:21,000 --> 00:00:30,000 
    How are you doing
```

File2.txt

```
    0
    00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:10,000
    Subtitle BY Name
    Synced By Name
    
    1
    00:00:11,000 --> 00:00:20,000 
    Hello
    2
    00:00:21,000 --> 00:00:30,000 
    How are you doing
```

I found this code "rename the file which should be appended to intro (or anything without .txt extension), then you can use a FOR loop over *.txt files in a batch file"

```
@echo off
for /R  "C:\Users\Mr-Oussama\Desktop\intro\MylistText" %%a in (*.srt) do type intro >> %%a
pause
```

It works fine. But I want the text to appear on the first line, not at the end

I found this program when adding a text an error message appears

[PSA Insert Text to SRT](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Other-VIDEO-Tools/PSA-Insert-Text-to-SRT.shtml)

Is there anyone with an idea of any program or required order? works on Windows

Comment: What does this have to do with Python or the `echo` command?

Comment: I have a Windows 7 system and I want any method that works by using a Python or a command line

Comment: Write a python script that takes two filenames as arguments. It reads both files into variables, concatenate the variables, then writes this back out to the file that should be updated.

Comment: I have no idea to write a text in python script . Is it possible to modify the code above so that text appears in the first line?

Comment: I don't know, I don't know Windows batch programming.

Comment: If you don't know how to do this in Python, why did you say that python is an option?

Comment: On Unix you would do `cat intro.txt file1.txt > file1.txt.new && mv file1.txt.new file1.txt` I don't know what the Windows equivalent is.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code Payton

```
import glob

for file in glob.glob('./*txt'):
    with open(file.replace('.txt', '-out.txt'), 'w') as outfile:
        with open(file) as infile:
            text = infile.readlines()
            text.insert(0, "header\n")

            outfile.write(''.join(text))

            infile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

He's working. Instead of writing a text, how do you specify a text?
Like changing a text "header" to file path intro.txt
header = \Desktop\new\intro.txt